# Logic behind storing a max number of user favorites to SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm wanting to store a number of different user favorites (in this example a max of 5) in sharedpreferences.
The user will be able to add and delete these favorites from within the app.

I'm having trouble getting my head around how to achieve this (I assume some sort of looping is needed).
The gist of what I'm trying to do when a user adds a new favorite:

```
//init prefs
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "PREFS";
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = null;
SharedPreferences.Editor sharedPreferencesEditor;

//onCreate
sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

//method called when user adds new favorite
public void addFavorite(String fav) {

    //int i = 0;
    //int maxFavs = 5;

    //check how many favorites are already stored in shared prefs, if any (is it under maxFavs?)
    //if over maxFavs, display error
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Favorite added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //else continue
    //upon finding available favorite 'space' (less than permitted maxFavs), add to favorites in shared prefs
            sharedPreferencesEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            sharedPreferencesEditor.putString("fav_" + i, fav);
            sharedPreferencesEditor.apply();
    }
```

Am I getting the right idea here, or is there a better way to do what I'm intending to do? Hopefully it's clear from the above.

Answer (score 0):

Store favorite count in preferences as an int and read & update it as needed. Also it would be better if you store favorites in preferences as (key : favoritedItemId, value boolean)

Even better: Use a proper local database for situations like this. Preferences is a primitive key value type storage intended for simplier cases like storing a users light mode preference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Having a database for 5 short strings is overkill and I want to avoid that and use sharedpreferences which should be more than capable of handling it.
I just need to make sure the user doesn't use it liberally, it's about the logic to see which ones are in use and which ones are free i.e. "fav_[1-5]". 
Storing the count in preferences is only going to help with seeing if it's hit the limit or not, not the name to give it if they add a new one and it's under the limit, especially when user starts deleting certain ones.

Answer (score 0):

Gave up and created a simple database following the example here:

https://inducesmile.com/android/android-sqlite-database-example-tutorial/

Still, if anyone has a solution I'd be interested to see!